# How to secure MySQL from SQL Injection?

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to prevent SQL Injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

This is my SQL Query and I want to make it SQL injection free

```
 $q1="insert into ecat_user(login_id,password,fullname,gender,disp_name,dob,";
 $q1.="street_addr,city,country,zip,email,aol,msn,icq,yahoo,homepg_link,homepg_caption,description,";
 $q1.="legal_guardian,phoneno,promotioncode,user_type,height,weight,chest,waist,inseam,eyecolor,haircolor,";
 $q1.="shoesize,biceps,collar,experience,travel,notes,added_on,updated_on) values('$modelName','$password','$firstName',";
 $q1.="'$gender','$description','$dob','$streetAddress','$city','$country','$zipCode','$emailAddress',";
 $q1.="'$aolID','$msnID','$icqID','$msnID','$homePage','$homePageCaption','$description','$legalGuardian',";
 $q1.="'$phoneNumber','$promotionalCode','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','')";
 mysql_query($q1, $Conn);
 $id = mysql_insert_id();
```

Please suggest.

Comment: [http://php.net/mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) specifically [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to start off with.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: see http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php

Answer (score 6):

Stop using the ancient, soon to be deprecated `mysql_*` functions, and start using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) instead. Take a look at the documentation for [`PDO::prepare()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) to see an example.

Also take a look at the manual page about [choosing an API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php), which states:

> It is recommended to use either the [`mysqli`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO_MySQL`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extensions. It is not recommended to use the old mysql extension for new development.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how you are getting your variables.

The best and safest way is to use prepared statements. You *can* do these with `mysql_*` statements, but using PDO is probably a better option again.

This is an esample of using prepared statements in PDO:

```
<?php
/* Execute a prepared statement by passing an array of values */
$sql = 'SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$sth->execute(array(':calories' => 150, ':colour' => 'red'));
$red = $sth->fetchAll();
$sth->execute(array(':calories' => 175, ':colour' => 'yellow'));
$yellow = $sth->fetchAll();
?>
```

The idea is you prepare the statement - that tells the database *what* it should expect, then you pass the arguments to it with the array during the execute statement. anything funny is taken right out of the equation.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all values with placeholders and prepare the statment before sending it. For instance with PDO.

Answer (score 0):

You've got two options - Escaping the special characters in your unsafe_variable, or using a parameterized query. Both would protect you from SQL Injection. The parameterized query is considered better practice, but escaping characters in your variable will require fewer changes.

This is clearly described and cleared in the above article, please go through it compeletly.

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)